# rails postgreSQL cannot get this query to work (SUM, Group Order)

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

This query work when I try it in SQLite:

```
Transaction.where(:paid => true).select("created_at, SUM(amount) amount").group("DATE(created_at)").order('created_at')
```

But when I run it with postgreSQL it doesn'y work.
Heres the error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "transactions.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function : SELECT created_at, SUM(amount) as amount FROM "transactions" WHERE ("transactions"."paid" = 't') GROUP BY DATE(created_at) ORDER BY created_at
```

Anyone who can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not developing on top of SQLite but deploying on top of PostgreSQL (i.e. Heroku), are you?

Comment: If you stick the error message into the search box, you will get some useful answers.  This is becoming a bit of a FAQ.

Comment: @mu Yes I'm deploying it on Heroku. That's why it works local but not on Heroku

Answer (score 1):

You have to either use `DATE(created_at)` in the select clause, or use `created_at` in the group by clause.

Comment: Probably a throw-away `DATE(created_at)` in the column list would be the better choice.

Comment: @mu is too short, I'd agree performance-wise, but not knowing OP's intentions and context didn't want to assume :)

Comment: I cannot just throw-away the DATE(created_at). I need to see the total amount grouped by the date it was created.

Comment: @Christian: Just to be clear:
`Transaction.where(:paid => true).select("DATE(created_at) dt_created_at, SUM(amount) amount").group("DATE(created_at)").order('DATE(created_at)')` didn't work either?

Comment: @Christian: Here's my suggestion: 1) run just the SQL query in PGadmin. If it works, you are half-way there. 2) Try throwing out the DATE() and grouping by just created_at and also using that in the select statement. If Rails gives you what you expect, that would just mean that Rails doesn't like group("Date(created_at)"), in which case you'd have to make your query a bit more complex (subquery potentially), which makes the ActiveRecord party a bit uglier.

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting `created_at, sum(amount)`, ordering by `created_at`, but are grouping by  `date(created_at)`. The latter will disallow the use of anything but the grouped by fields and aggregates except in the join/where clause.

To fix, either group by `created_at`, or select *and* order by `date(created_at)` instead of `created_at`.

Comment: It did not get the result as I hoped. (I got the amount but did not get the date in the return objekt

Comment: `select created_at::date, sum(amount) from tbl group by created_at::date order by created_at::date`

Comment: **HERE IS MY CODE:** MonetaryTransaction.where(:paid => true).select("DATE(created_at), SUM(amount) as amount").group("DATE(created_at)").order('DATE(created_at)')
**HERE IS THE RESULT:** => [#<MonetaryTransaction amount: 1>, #<MonetaryTransaction amount: 1>, #<MonetaryTransaction amount: 1>, #<MonetaryTransaction amount: 4>]
The result does not contain the date object.

Comment: Dunno what to suggest... Use Sequel instead of Active Record? (The guy behind Sequel is quite competent at Postgres).